# Replacing non-printables with their vi editor code using sed

Tags: regex, sed, csh

Hi Everyone: I'm having an issue with the sed program

Problem:

I'm a CS student just learning Unix and I've been tasked to replace the non-printing character `\x00` to `\x1F` NUL to US with their Vi editor equivalent notation. For example where ever there is a BEL character (\x07) I replace that with ^G.

The file (called input3) I have to convert contains the following:

```
:Control-R:
:Escape:   
:Control-T:
:Control-_:
```

My teacher place the non-printables on either side of the colons. My solution has to use the Unix Utilities in particular sed.

My Solution:

So I used the following sed command to do such a task just for the Control-T guy for starters:

```
cat input3 | sed 's/\024/^T/g'
```

But it doesn't work it just send the same file to standard output. Is there something wrong with my sed command. My locale is POSIX and I'm using the C-shell. This has to be done using the C-shell.

Comment: I hope your `^T` is a your result of pressing the <tab> key, and not typing 2 separate chars, `^`, and `T`, the latter will not work. Good luck!

Comment: It has to be replaced by two separate characters ^ and T. lol. Thanks though for telling me it doesn't work. I'll have to read the man page a little more for sed, and look around the net. : D

Comment: Sorry, should have said earlier, `^T` can be produced with the <tab> key OR by pressing Ctrl-T (hold Control key and press T). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you used was not what you thought it was: `\024` is evaluated as simply the string "024". If you look at the [sed escapes references](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html#Escapes) posted by @Alex, there is no special treatment for `\0`, so `\0` becomes simply "0", and of course `24` remains "24". For example:

```
$ echo hello 024 joe | sed 's/\024/^T/g'
hello  joe
```

So, since you want to replace the character with octal value `024`, you have to use the right format for octal values, as @Alex already wrote:

```
cat input3 | sed 's/\o024/^T/g'
```

You could use hexa values too, if that's easier:

```
cat input3 | sed 's/\x14/^T/g'
```

(that's not a typo, `024` converted to hexa is `0x14`)

Based on the sed reference above, there's an even more readable version:

```
cat input3 | sed 's/\ct/^T/g'
```

That is, you can use `\c` to match Control-*X* where *X* is any character. This works nicely for Control-T, Control-R, Control-_ in your example input, but it won't work for Control-ESCAPE, because there is no ASCII character for ESCAPE (and `\c[` doesn't work). For that you really need to use the octal or hexa representation of Control-ESCAPE.

Extra tip: you can use `hexdump` to find the hexa codes of your input, for example:

```
$ hexdump -C input3
00000000  3a 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c  2d 52 3a 12 0a 3a 45 73  |:Control-R:..:Es|
00000010  63 61 70 65 3a 1b 0a 3a  43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 2d  |cape:..:Control-|
00000020  54 3a 14 0a 3a 43 6f 6e  74 72 6f 6c 2d 5f 3a 1f  |T:..:Control-_:.|
00000030  0a
```

So, to replace Control-ESCAPE:

```
cat input3 | sed 's/\x1b/^[/'
```

Finally, to replace multiple patterns with one `sed` command, you'll need to separate the `s///` commands by `;`, or by using multiple `-e` flags, for example these both work:

```
cat input3 | sed 's/\ct/^T/;s/\cr/^R/'
cat input3 | sed -e 's/\ct/^T/' -e 's/\cr/^R/'
```

Using multiple `-e` is more portable, as it works in older versions of `sed` too.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I'll make sure to try your command later on, when I have the chance. I got a Java project to work on as well. Thanks for your help, janos.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing escaping the octal value `024`.

Try this instead:

```
cat input3 | sed 's/\o024/^T/g'
```

You may find this [sed escapes reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html#Escapes) useful.